# rebase whilst maintaing merge history

Tags: git, git-rebase

The `git` workflow that I like best is to `rebase` everything before committing to `master`, but also to make use of `git merge --no-ff` to create a history that has readable, identifiable chunks of work, and fine detail within those chunks of work.

Using `--no-ff` gives a history that looks kinda like this:

```
|
|\
| \
|  |FeatureA.InterestingStep1
|  |FeatureA.InterestingStep2
|  |FeatureA.InterestingStep3
|  |FeatureA.InterestingStep4
|  |FeatureA.InterestingStep5
| /
|/
|FeatureA
|\
| \
|  |FeatureB.InterestingStep1
|  |FeatureB.InterestingStep2
|  |FeatureB.InterestingStep3
| /
|/
|FeatureB
```

That's all fine.

What's a shame is that if I try to rebase this, then I lose the structure.

Suppose that I've finished my work, fetched, rebased, cleaned up the merge conflicts, cleaned up my local messy commit history to be the (still multiple) final commits I want on master and built the necessary `--no-ff` structure.

Then I push, but someone else on the team has beaten me to the punch and origin\master has moved.
If I rebase, then the `-no-ff` structure disappears and I'm left with a linear commit sequence.

Recreating it isn't the end of the world, but is there a way to rebase without losing the structure?

Comment: Try `-p` or `--preserve-merges`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `-p` (or `--preserve-merges`) option of `rebase` which *preserves merge commits*

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---preserve-merges):

> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying
>   commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict resolutions or
>   manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Francesco
You may also want to look out for git pull --rebase which many developers use. It also flattens the history. The way to avoid that is by doing fetch/rebase manually i.e (being on master)

`git fetch`

`git rebase --preserve-merges origin/master`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As it happens I already do this everytime as I like to have manual control of the steps, but I'm sure others who do use `pull --rebase` will find this useful :)